# What is the best material for 200Hz power inductor?

Tags: inductor, magnetics

I am looking for inductor core material working at about 200Hz. The inductor current is DC only, close to triangle with 5A average.
I read for such purpose the amorphous alloys have a good performance, however they are not available in local stores.
Is there some other option?
I am thinking about audio transformer and cut some air-gap to get wider BH. Is it a good idea?

Comment: What do you mean by a wider BH? An air-gap makes the BH curve flatter.

Comment: @Andyaka My bad. But anyway, should and air-gap increase the inductance at the same winding turns? According my experiences it increases somehow.

Comment: @MichalP What??? The air gap increases the reluctance. Perhaps a better way to think of this is that the non-air core material has a relative permeability, \$\mu_r\$. If you divide the physical path length, as measured by a ruler, by this number then you get the effective vacuum magnetic path length. When you cut a gap, this gap directly adds. Suppose \$\mu_r=2000\$ and the physical magnetic loop of the core is 20 cm. Then the effective vacuum path is 100 microns. If you now cut an air gap of 300 microns then the total will be about 400 microns. Inductance drops by ~4X (3.9985, actually.)

Comment: @MichalPodmanický an air-gap decreases inductance for the same number of turns.

Comment: @MichalP You can compute the reduction factor in inductance, for a given gap, as \$1+\frac{\text{gap}}{\text{starting path length}}\cdot\left(\mu_r-1\right)\$. In my example this calculates out as 3.9985. Note that if the gap is zero, this works out as expected. And that if the entire core is air so that \$\mu_r=1\$ this also works out as expected.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for answers, periblepsis also. So what is best shape of BH for an  inductor if I want to minimize number of turns?

Comment: The shape of the BH curve is not related to wanting to minimize the number of turns; it's a bit like relating the BHP of a car engine to the colour it's painted @MichalPodmanický

Comment: To design an inductor to do what you want requires information about the application, the operating frequencies, the terminal voltages and any likely DC current @MichalPodmanický